# Calculating the sum of a 'mpfr' list in r

Tags: r, list, sum

I would like to get the sum of the following list:

```
library(Rmpfr)
n <- 50
j <- 25

#1
sigma <- 0.3
theta <- 25
m <- 20
k <- 8
CgenC <- function(n,k,sigma){
i <- 0:k
B <- (-1)^i *choose(k,i)*pochMpfr((-i)*sigma, n)
CgenC <- sum(B)*1/(factorial(k))
return(CgenC)
}
h <- sapply(i,CgenC,k=k,sigma=sigma)
sum(h)
```

Since I am using the package 'Rmpfr, h is a list and looks like:

```
> h
[[1]]
1 'mpfr' number of precision  424   bits 
[1]         6.56100000001090797674407895165123852486764558494011370343385553818846334039114391208397490584873828362680520137726767534538684455e-5

[[2]]
1 'mpfr' number of precision  477   bits 
[1]    0.00165337200000076007515956849631156412592784160499700109400458694583908280540322124291285331063187104152797429852422246700297812973405724306364625

 ... and so on
```

What can I do to get the sum of the values in h?
Thanks in advance!